# C++ - std::unique_ptr in vector<> is nullptr

Tags: c++, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I want to store `Particle` objects in a `vector` object, so I can access it later.
These particles (`Electrons` and `Protons`) are inherited from the `Particle` class which contains a `toString()` virtual method. This `toString()` method is then overrided in `Electron` and `Proton` classes.

When I read the vector container, I want to access to the `toString()` method specific to `Electron` or `Proton`, and not to `Particle`.

Apparently, one way is to use `std::unique_ptr`. Here is the part of the code I try to run:

```cpp
int main(){
    /**/
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Particle>> particles(nbParticles);

    particles.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Electron>( new Electron(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)));
    particles.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Proton>(new Proton(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)));
    particles.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Particle>(new Particle(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0)));

    if (particles[0]==nullptr){
        std::cout<< "index=0 : nullptr"<<std::endl; //There is a null_ptr at particles[0]
    }

    if (particles[2]==nullptr){
        std::cout<< "index=2 : nullptr"<<std::endl; //There is not a null_ptr at particles[2]
    }

    std::cout<<particles[0]->toString()<<std::endl; //This is what I'm trying to do
    /**/
}
```

A pointer to a `Particle` object seems to be fine, but not to an `Electron` or `Proton`. I guess there is something wrong with the constructors ?

```cpp
class Particle
{
public:
    Particle();
    Particle(double mass, double charge, double posX, double posY, double posZ);
    virtual std::string toString() const;
}

class Electron : public Particle
{
public:
    Electron(double PosX, double PosY, double PosZ);
    virtual std::string toString() const;
}

class Proton : public Particle
{
public:
    Proton(double PosX, double PosY, double PosZ);
    virtual std::string toString() const;
}
```

and the definitions:

```cpp
Particle::Particle(double mass, double charge, double posX, double posY, double posZ) :
    m_mass(mass), m_charge(charge),
    m_posX(posX), m_posY(posY), m_posZ(posZ) {}


Electron::Electron(double PosX, double PosY, double PosZ) :
    Particle(9.109E-31, -1.602E-19, PosX, PosY, PosZ){}

Proton::Proton(double PosX, double PosY, double PosZ) :
    Particle(9.109E-31, +1.602E-19, PosX, PosY, PosZ){}
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior because `Particle` doesn't have a `virtual` destructor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've made a classic mistake that trips up even the most experienced C++ programmers: you declared the vector with an initial size and then `push_back`ed additional elements to it instead of assigning to the existing elements. Fix this by removing the `(nbParticles)` from the vector initialization.

Comment: Might want to add they should add a call to reserve if the know ow many elements there will be.  That way they don't have to g through multiple reallocations.

Comment: Thank you, it works now :)
But why the pointer on `Particle`object was non `nullptr` whereas the ones on the inherited types were `nullptr`?

Comment: @T0T0R Just a guess, did you set `nbParticles` to 1 or 2?

Comment: To be precise, it was 
    int nbElectrons{1};
    int nbProtons{1};
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Particle>> particles(nbElectrons+nbProtons);
so yes

Comment: @T0T0R What you can do is `particles.reserve(3);` before the `push_back()`s, to allocate memory only once. It's premature optimization though...

Comment: Technically, then... the bug was in the code not provided, since the bug was in `nbParticles`.  Keen insight, Brian!

Comment: @zett42 Using `reserve` when you know the size is **absolutely not premature optimization**. Premature optimization is harming the readability / maintainability of the code or increasing the complexity of the code to make code run faster *without measuring that it's needed*. `particles.reserve(3);` *improves* the readability / maintainability of the code - it clearly communicates, "I know the size of this vector beforehand". Without it, the code communicates an uncertainty about what size the vector will be.

Comment: If you leave out all the calls to `vec.reserve(n);` and do similarly for other similar cases in C++, that's the recipe for making it hard to go back through and speed up the code. Profiling would be unlikely to show any specific place as slow, because everything is a little slow. Going through later to add in the calls to `vec.reserve(n);` would be prohibitively expensive. It's far better to code it right in the first place.

Comment: @Justin ... until the next dev comes and adds a `push_back` somewhere down the function, not noticing the `reserve()` at the top. It's nothing more than writing a comment "I will add 3 elements to the vector here", which will be outdated as soon as someone changes the code.

Comment: @zett42 True, there's an argument for not using `reserve` in this case, since you don't necessarily know the size if someone might think it's a good idea to add a `push_back` somewhere else. In this case, however, I'd probably make the vector `const`, meaning that all the initialization has to be in the same spot. `vec.reserve(3);` followed by four calls to `push_back` is very easy to catch in code review. Alternatively, something like an initializer list works really well for cases like this (would have to be a variadic helper function to avoid the copies from `initializer_list`)